# Solr filter by year on TrieDateField

Tags: solr

My Solr schema has a fieldtype `tdate` of class `solr.TrieDateField`

```
<field name="timestamp" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW"/>
```

So when I add documents to the index the timestamp field looks like this:

```
"timestamp": "2015-11-03T15:52:51.418Z"
```

Now to filter all documents of the *current* year I add a range filter to the query:

```
/select?q=*:*&fq=timestamp:[NOW/YEAR TO NOW/YEAR+1YEAR}
```

But how would I filter for *any* year, let's say 2014?

The only thing I could come up with was to create a date range spanning the entire year from the first to the last millisecond:

```
/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&fq=timestamp:[2014-01-01T0:00:00.000Z TO 2014-12-31T23:59:59.999Z}
```

Is there a way to get to the same result by just passing in the year as a four digit string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I believe it is not possible for a TrieDateField to filter on year granularity, other than the proposed solution. You would need a `solr.DateRangeField` for that.

However it is possible to add a single argument to the query string telling Solr how to conceive `NOW`, which is an `epoch` time (milliseconds) chosen in the year we want to filter by.

```
&fq=timestamp:[NOW/YEAR TO NOW/YEAR+1YEAR}&NOW=1388534400000
```

`1388534400000` represents midnight the 1st of january 2014. But any other `epoch` timestamp representing a moment in 2014 will be fine.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates