# Solr query TrieDateField by milliseconds

Tags: solr

I have a field that is indexed as a TrieDateField.

Is it possible to query this field using milliseconds since epoch?

For example, given schema:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
<field name="my_date" type="date"/>
```

And an indexed document:

```
{
    "my_date": "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I want to query for this document using milliseconds since epoch:

```
q=my_date:[1325376000000 TO 1325376000001]
```

However, when I try that, I get an error:

```
"error": {
    "msg": "Invalid Date String:'1325376000000'",
    "code": 400
}
```

Is there any way I can support this type of query?

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520332/solr-filter-by-year-on-triedatefield

Comment: @BinoyDalal Thanks. Figured it out using the technique described in the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a little weird syntactically, but it is possible to do by re-defining `NOW`.

The working query would be:

```
q=tile_min_time_dt:[NOW TO NOW]&NOW=1325376000000
```